# Connect to an available wireless network using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, connect, wireless

Using VB.NET how do I connect to an available wireless network. I have been able to list all the available networks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are wanting to control the Windows biult-in wifi stack, you should be able to do it with the [WlanConnect Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706613%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). A signature is availeble at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi/WlanConnect.html).

MSDN has a list of the articles pertaining to wifi [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The MSDN page does not say whether this is the case, but an application might need elevated permissions to use this API...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the WLAN profile saved in your PC, this approach is simple.

```
Sub connectTo(ByVal name As String)
    Dim p = "netsh.exe"
    Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(p, "wlan connect " & name)
    sInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    sInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Process.Start(sInfo)
End Sub

'use the sub to connect to your AP. connectTo("myAP")
```

Otherwise, it is easier to use [ManagedWifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) or [SimpleWifi](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi) dll libraries. Here is my [code](https://github.com/lahiiru/QuotaClientApps/blob/master/QuotaWin/QuotaService/QuotaService.vb#L427) where I used SimpleWifi.dll to connect to a network with a passkey.