# Connect to WiFi Network from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, networking

I am adding a feature to my personal web browser that can connect to optimumwifi, but I have no idea for a command I should use. I found [this for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706613%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but I have no idea for VB.NET. It is a button you push that will execute the command, but I don't know how I should connect to an open network, or any network for that matter.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928408/using-c-sharp-or-powershell-to-scan-all-available-wireless-networks-and-connect. You could launch `netsh` from VB.Net to connect for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to an available wireless network using VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771128/connect-to-an-available-wireless-network-using-vb-net)